# pigeonhole principle cube problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

i got this problem that **we need to prove that we *cannot*** **pick 28 points that are 1.75cm(atleast) from eachother in a cube where each edge is 3cm long .**

i tried $dividing$ each square in the cube to $4$ , that way we will get that each edge is $1.5cm$ now and the hypotenuse will be $2.12$ $\left(\frac{3\sqrt 2}{2}\right)$ i did this because i think its the smallest distance we can get

now since a cube has 6 squares , and my squares are divided to have 4 smaller cubes in each one we get $4*6=24$ which leaves us 4 extra points which means some squares will have $2$ points in them but i cannot tell if i did right or even close to it because of the information in the question (**atleast 1.75 distance between each point)**
i tried to demonstrate what i meant [image]

thanks to any helpers , and sorry if there are translation mistakes

Comment: Try using 1 cm and its corresponding √3 diagonals. You will find 3•3•3=27 boxes. If there is another point, it will be less than √3 cm from one of the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is the number 28, which is one more than 27, which is $3^3$

Hint: Divide the cube into 27 smaller cubes of side length $1$ cm.